# Ansible - Printing output with jinja2 template

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2

I have a host file as such.

```
[my_dg1]
10.20.30.15
10.20.30.16
```

I am using the following jinja2 template

```
{% for host in groups['my_dg1'] %}
{{ host }} Hostname: {{device_facts.devices[0].hostname }}
{{ host }} Management IP: {{ private_ip }}
{% endfor %}
```

The private_ip and the hostname were captured using device facts

I am expecting to print

```
10.20.30.15 Hostname: test15.test.net
10.20.30.15 Management 10.20.30.15
10.20.30.16 Hostname: test16.test.net
10.20.30.16 Management IP: 10.20.30.16
```

Instead its printing

```
10.20.30.15 Hostname: test15.test.net
10.20.30.15 Management IP: 10.20.30.15
10.20.30.16 Hostname: test15.test.net
10.20.30.16 Management IP: 10.20.30.15
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page,
and pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section. As written, we have no idea where `private_ip` is coming from, but it seems like just a simple typo in that you're not referencing `host_vars[host]` in that loop

Comment: Change your vars to `{{ hostvars[host].device_facts.devices[0].hostname }}` and `{{ hostvars[host].private_ip }}`. For reference, search for "Ansible magic variables" in your favorite search engine

Comment: @Zeitounator that was it. Using the ansible magic variables I was able to print all sort of facts. Thank you and much obliged.